# Ubuntu mate keyboard layouts adding problem

Tags: keyboard, mate, layout

After updating of system keyboard is broken! I can not add keyboard layout! Button "Add" is disabled!

How I can restore the system?

[image: See here]

---

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE 
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page. 
XKBMODEL="pc105" 
XKBLAYOUT="us" 
XKBVARIANT="" 
XKBOPTIONS="" 
BACKSPACE="guess"

$ apt-cache policy mate-control-center
mate-control-center: 
  Installed: 1.20.2-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.20.2-2ubuntu1 
  Version table: 
 *** 1.20.2-2ubuntu1 500 
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is your MATE version? What do you mean by "After updating of system keyboard "? Please add output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` and `apt-cache policy mate-control-center` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1198865/edit).

Comment: Also please add output of `gsettings list-recursively org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd` to the question.

Comment: `$ cat /etc/default/keyboard

# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"

XKBLAYOUT="us"

XKBVARIANT=""

XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"`

Comment: `$ apt-cache policy mate-control-center
mate-control-center:
  Installed: 1.20.2-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.20.2-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.2-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `/etc/default/keyboard` to correct values with single long command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/default/keyboard 
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE 
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page. 
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
BACKSPACE="guess"

EOF
```

and then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
and then you can set keyboard layouts from Keyboard Preferences (`mate-keyboard-properties`) .

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working!

Comment: Great, so you can accept my answer :)

Comment: How can I mark your answer correctly? I do not see the corresponding button or link

Comment: Thanks, you did it right :)